# Flutter Grouping Static Classes removes constant from field, why?

Tags: flutter, class, static, constants

When creating a class for static Color resources in flutter and grouping these into sub classes, implementation of the asset later causes an error stating that the static const resource is not a constant value even though it is declared as a static const and the sub class has only final fields. What is going on?

The following code groups static resources.

```
class AppColor {
static const _Label label = _Label();

}

class _Label {
  const _Label();
  final Color primary = const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1);
  final Color secondary = const Color.fromRGBO(46, 52, 58, 0.84);
}
```

However when using this resource in a Widget constructor it shows the error:

```
class AWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  AWidget({
    super.key,
    Color color = AppColor.label.primary, 
    //!!!  The default value of an optional parameter must be constant
  });
  final Color color;
}
```

Why? It is constant is it not? This problem only occurs when grouping the static resources. If I list them all in `AppColor` then this does not happen but its not friendly to do that with the amount of resources I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In constructors, you can only use variables initialized with `const` as an optional parameter value, which means that they must be known at compile time.

You are getting this error because `primary` field in `Label` class is intitialized with `final` not `const`.